# Как отследить, что приложение на андроид было свернуто?

Tags: java, android

Нужно, чтобы при сворачивании приложения оно закрывалось.

Comment: Почитай про [Жизненный цикл активити](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/lifecycle.php) если используешь фрагменты то почитай [Жизненный цикл фрагментов](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragment-lifecycle.php) там написано все максимально доступно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Хотя так делать не рекомендуется, но можно в onStop убить весь процесс приложения полностью:

```
public void onStop() {
    android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
    super.onStop();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

> Как отследить, что приложение на андроид было свернуто?

При сворачивании приложения, вызывается метод `onStop()` активити. Переопределите этот метод и реализуйте в нем функционал по закрытию приложения.

Но вообще, в Android **не нужно вручную закрывать приложения**. Управление состоянием приложений – это функции самой ОС, которая, при необходимости, сама выгрузит Ваше приложение из памяти.

При сворачивании Вашего приложения, вызовется метод `onStop()` активити, а после него метод `onDestroy()`, после которого Ваша активити будет завершена. Но все это не приведет к немедленному завершению приложения.

Есть хороший [пост от CommonsWare](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2034238/7129209) на эту тему.